# @Autowired bean null when inside at least two levels of components

Tags: spring, jsf

I have the following structure:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class ListCompaniesBean {

    @Autowired
    private JsfUtil jsfUtil;
...

@Component
public class JsfUtil {

    @Autowired
    private ComponentLookup componentLookup;
...

@Component
public class ComponentLookup {
...
```

Spring creates the `ListCompaniesBean` and autowires `JsfUtil` without any problem, but for some reason `ComponentLookup` comes `null` when I use it inside `ListCompaniesBean`. If I create a new field on `ListCompaniesBean` and autowire `ComponentLookup` it is created normaly, seems that I can't create beans inside beans until some level, does anyone had this problem?

I'm not creating new instances of any of them, `JstUtil` and `ComponentLookup` are in a separate jar, and everything is on an EAR with a shared context, if you need more information just tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by moving to constructor injection and see if that exposes the problem.

Comment: Hi @chrylis, your advice helped me a lot! I found a dependency that was missing, I'm still working on it but I could move, thanks.